# Undo a mass rename of files in a directory?

Tags: files, rename, data-recovery

So I tried to use this script to get rid of a username in a bunch of files

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | while read -r FILE
do
    mv -v "$FILE" `echo $FILE | tr '[DarkDream]' '.' `
done
```

Instead, all of the files that had the letters **d, a, r, k, e** and **m** got replace with **a**.

Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: I assume by now that you've done 'man tr' and realized that tr replaces (i.e. "TRanslates") from one character SET to another set, and does not replace strings?

You should have used: 
mv -v "$FILE" `echo "$FILE" | sed -e "s/DarkDream//"`

Comment: @Bytor A better solution would have been to use Robin Barker's `rename` (packaged by many distributions) like so: `rename 's/DarkDream//' *`

Comment: Do you still have the output from running that script? If so, it might very well be possible to make a script that undoes the damage, because with `-v`, `mv` will print the original and new file name for every file that gets moved or renamed.

Comment: You say "all of the files that had the letters **d, a, r, k, e** and **m** got replace with **a**."  Huh?  Do you mean "Every file whose name contained any of **`D`**, **`a`**, **`r`**, **`k`**, **`e`**, and **`m`** got renamed to the same name, with all of those letters replaced by periods (**`.`**); e.g., `cat`, `dog`, `meerkat`, and `Dog` got renamed to `c.t`, `dog`, `......t`, and `.og`, respectively."?  Did any files get clobbered, or is this just a rename problem?

Comment: Small trick for future, prepend a critical command with `echo` so you can verify it does exactly what you expect.
Though that might require modification of the original command.

Answer (score 5):

If you've a snapshot of the filesystem, or a backup, then yes.

If you haven't, then no.

Comment: Well, there is (rather was) a way: copying the output from his verbose `cp -v` command and swapping the input and output files in a simple script

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way also using the [locate database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) and writing a custom script... The database is regularly updated, but usually it is updated once in the day only so you can get a snapshot of the file names if you are fast enough.